Is it possible to get the owner of a file from S3 bucket
I am new to aws and have been tasked with a few aws s3 related items. One is can I get the owner of a file in S3.  Multiple people are uploading files to S3, but I would like to get the original owner. After downloading any file locally it has me as the owner when I check the properties.
Checking S3 it looks like the only metadata is type, last modified, size, storage class and ETag.

Multiple people as in multiple different AWS accounts? Anyways, your bucket is likely operating in bucket owner preferred/enforced mode, where the owner of the uploaded object will always be the bucket owner: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html

Amazon S3 does not have the concept of users as 'owners. When an upload request is made to S3, the credentials are checked to confirm that they have permission to perform the upload. If so, the upload is accepted and the object then becomes 'owned' by the AWS Account rather than a specific user. You could use Tags to track ownership, but you would need to add this information to the object as part of the upload, rather than having it automatically recorded by S3.
